# How to open device's contact screen by swipe in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

[image]

I'm using bottom navigation , and when I navigate from Dialer screen to contacts screen by swiping, at that time I want to open phone's contact screen directly.
Below I have shared the code of ContactComponent file and BottomNavigation file.
I'm new in React Native, so please help me in this.
Thanks in  advance.

ContactComponent.js

```
 const ContactComponents = ({ navigation }) => {
 useEffect(() => {
   Linking.openURL("content://com.android.contacts/contacts")
  }, []);

 }
 export default ContactComponents
```

BottomNavigation.js

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
export default function BottomNavigation() {
return (
  <Tab.Navigator
  tabBarPosition='bottom'
  initialRouteName='Dialer'
  screenOptions={{ 
    tabBarLabelPosition: "beside-icon",
    //tabBarLabelStyle: { fontWeight: "700", fontSize: 15, color : 'white'},
    tabBarIconStyle: { display: "none" },
    tabBarStyle :{backgroundColor : bottomTabBarColor},
    tabBarIndicatorStyle : {position : 'relative', borderWidth : 2 , borderColor : bottomTabBarIndicatorColor}
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen 
      
      name="Messages" 
      component={MessageComponent} 
      options = {{
        tabBarLabel: ({focused, color, size}) => (
          <Text style={ [styles.textStyle, {color: focused ? focusedLabelColor : unfocusedLableColor , fontWeight : focused ? 'bold' : 'normal' }] }>Messages </Text>
        ),
      }}
    />


    <Tab.Screen 
        name="Last Ones" 
        component={LastOnesComponent} 
        options = {{
          tabBarLabel: ({focused, color, size}) => (
            <Text style={ [styles.textStyle, {color: focused ? focusedLabelColor : unfocusedLableColor , fontWeight : focused ? 'bold' : 'normal' }] }>Last Ones </Text>
          ),
        }}
    />

    <Tab.Screen 
        name="Dialer" 
        component={Dialpad} 
        options = {{
          tabBarLabel: ({focused, color, size}) => (
            <Text style={ [styles.textStyle, {color: focused ? focusedLabelColor : unfocusedLableColor , fontWeight : focused ? 'bold' : 'normal' }] }>Dialer </Text>
          ),
        }}
    />


    <Tab.Screen 
        name="Contacts" 
        component={ContactComponents} 
        options = {{
          tabBarLabel: ({focused, color, size}) => (
             //<View style={focused ?  styles.topTabLine : null}>
             <Text style={ [styles.textStyle, {color: focused ? focusedLabelColor : unfocusedLableColor , fontWeight : focused ? 'bold' : 'normal' }] }>Contacts </Text>
             //</View>
          ),
        }}
    />


  </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: https://aboutreact.com/access-contact-list-react-native/

Comment: I don't wanna to list out the contacts in my app, I just wanna to open phone's contact app directly when I swipe to the contact screen.

Comment: @Anand, it is possible. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, you can use native `Linking` from `react-native` to open the contacts app.

```js
const openContacts = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Linking.openURL('content://com.android.contacts/contacts');
  }
};
```

Now, if you want to open the contacts screen when the Dialer screen is focused, you can use the `useFocusEffect` hook from `@react-navigation/native` to perform that operation.

In the screen from which you want to navigate to contacts app, use this hook as shown.

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

.
.
.

useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.openURL('content://com.android.contacts/contacts');
    }
  }, [])
);
```

Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/open-contacts) for the implementation

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to open contact app on button click, I wanna open it on swipe. Is it possible? If yes, then please let me know How?

Comment: @Anjali I've updated the answer. Please check the Snack too. It has the working implementation.

Comment: One more thing I want to know that is it possible when I click on any contact from the contact list , then its only phone number value is fetched back in my app. If it is possible then is it possible with "react-native-contacts" library?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Instead, what you can do is let the user copy that contact number and when user comes back to your app, add a listener for `AppState`, so that when your app is focused, it checks the `clipboard` and if the last copied text is a mobile number then you can use that number.